# Raster io error while writing the GeotTiff

Tags: python, gis, geotiff, rasterio

I have clipped the raster and updated the new raster's meta data. I am facing the following issue while writing clipped image into an output file

**Code**

```
with rasterio.open('example.tif', 'w', **out_meta) as dst:
        dst.write(out_img, 1)
```

**Error**

````
  File "C:\Users\kvars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rasterio\env.py", line 442, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\kvars\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py", line 320, in open
    dataset = writer(
  File "rasterio\_io.pyx", line 1520, in rasterio._io.DatasetWriterBase.__init__
  File "rasterio\_io.pyx", line 1549, in rasterio._io.DatasetWriterBase._set_crs
  File "rasterio\crs.pyx", line 777, in rasterio.crs.CRS.from_user_input
rasterio.errors.CRSError: The WKT could not be parsed. OGR Error code 5```
````

Comment: This question is about a similar error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62429790/reprojecting-tiff-file-with-rasterio-crserror-the-wkt-could-not-be-parsed-og